# How to modify the `--registry-mirror` of a running docker machine?

Tags: docker, mirror, docker-machine

We can create a docker machine with `--registry-mirror`, e.g.:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-registry-mirror http://111222.m.daocloud.io mymachine
```

We will find the mirror url is in the boot2docker if we logged into the machine:

```
$ docker-machine ssh mymachine
$ cat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox
--registry-mirror http://111222.m.daocloud.io

'
CACERT=/var/lib/boot2docker/ca.pem
DOCKER_HOST='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376'
DOCKER_STORAGE=aufs
DOCKER_TLS=auto
SERVERKEY=/var/lib/boot2docker/server-key.pem
SERVERCERT=/var/lib/boot2docker/server.pem
```

And it will use this mirror when pulling images.

But how to change the mirror after the machine is created?

I tried to midify this `boot2docker/profile` file, but it seems not take effect. How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

After modifying `boot2docker/profile`, you need to restart the daemon (or the VM).

A command like `docker-machine ssh mymachine sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart` ought to be enough, but if not, just restart the VM (`docker-machine restart mymachine`) and your change should take.